# React/Typescript - How to handle different event types in single onChange handler function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I have a form which is built up of differing types of inputs, utilising the [mui](https://mui.com/) library. I want to take the values of differing types of input components, and store them within a single state in a Grandparent component. I am able to handle different types of inputs if they have the same Event function structure (i.e. `(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void`), but I am now using the [AutoComplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#main-content) component, and since it has a different onChange event handler, I am unsure as to how I would be able to process it's change within a single onChange handler.

Please look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dew-84027u?file=/src/components/Child3.tsx) link for the rough structure of the problem. I would like the input of `Child3` to be handled within the `getNameAndValueFromEvent()` method within `valueStates.ts` (which is called in `Grandparent.tsx`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Autocomplete's onChange event](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props) is slightly different than [TextField's onChange event](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props). As a result, you cannot directly handle them by a single value change handler function.

You can add a new value change handler for Autocomplete in Child3 component to send the required parameters for `valueChange` function.

Your `Child3` component can be like:

```
const Child3: React.FC<Props> = ({ id, valueChange }) => {
  const handleValueChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, val: string) => {
    const dataToBeSent = {
      target: {
        name: id,
        value: val
      }
    }
    valueChange(dataToBeSent, id)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        disableCloseOnSelect
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        filterSelectedOptions
        onChange={handleValueChange}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Child3"
            placeholder="Option"
            name={id}
          />
        )}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

You can take a look at [this forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-architecture-m5lcey?file=/src/components/Child3.tsx) for a live working example of this approach.

Comment: This implementation has inspired me to move all handling functions into each child component, and to then have the 'Master' handler in Grandparent to take in the 'dataToBeSent' in as a parameter instead of an event. Thanks for the answer!